# How to check if a domain usr is part of Local group

Tags: c++

I have a local machine MACHINE1.
A user creates a local group "Test1"
The user add a domain user "DOMAIN/USER1" to the local group "Test1"
I have tried calling 'NetLocalGroupGetMembers' but the function returns only the local user added and not the domain one.
If I check with the function 'NetUserGetLocalGroups', then it gives me the Local groups for the domain, not for the machine the user is logged into.

I would like to find out if the Domain user is a part of the user group in the machine.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I didn't try, but you may use `NetUserGetGroups`...

Comment: `NetLocalGroupGetMembers` with level=2? It says that it would return <DomainName>\<AccountName>

Comment: Thanks, but it still doesnt work.